# perl pie escape the delimeter

Tags: regex, perl

I'm running this perl cmd on Mac OS to delete the whole line.

```
perl -i -pe's/<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_app_id"/>/ /g' AndroidManifest.xml
```

The result is

```
fb_app_id"@string/fb_app_id"/>
```

I'm unable to escape the `/` in `"@string/fb_app_id` tried different variations `@string//fb_app_id` and `@string\/fb_app_id` but none worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had been using warnings, you would have been notified that `@strings` is being considered a variable and interpolated in the regex. You should try to escape the `@`. And also the slashes.

```
perl -i -pe's/<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\@string\/fb_app_id"\/>\/ /g' AndroidManifest.xml
```

Running a Perl command without warnings is a bad idea, even if you are a Perl expert.

Notable things:

- You should not parse XML with a regex. [Related infamous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/725418)
- You do not need to use a substitution, you can try a looser match using `m//` with the `-n` switch, and then avoid printing matching lines. E.g.

```
perl -i -nwe'print unless m|android:value="\@string/fb_app_id"|'
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using delimiter `[]` ?

```
perl -i -pe's[<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\@string/fb_app_id"/>][ ]g' AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, nothing changed. I'm running this cmd on mac os

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding the hazzards of using regex on XML, here is how you would normally do a task like this.

Use curly braces as the delimiters. `s{}{}`
Manually escape these characters. `$ @ \ --> \$ \@ \\`
If it's a fixed string, wrap it with `\Q\E`. Otherwise periods and other regex meta characters will cause unintended effects.

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's{\Q<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\@string/fb_app_id"/>\E}{ }g' AndroidManifest.xml
```

To merely comment out the block:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's{(\Q<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\@string/fb_app_id"/>\E)}{<!-- $1 -->}g' AndroidManifest.xml
```

HTH